# Prestashop doesn't installs

Tags: php, apache, xampp, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have xampp with PHP 7.3.2 installed on Windows 7.

I extracted the zip file that I downloaded from Prestashop website and I extracted it;
After doing that everything went fine except that on the "Store Installation" step I saw this error:

```
An error occurred during installation...

You can use the links on the left column to go back to the previous steps, or restart the installation process by clicking here.
1: Unable to write into "en-US"" (data layer : "PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Localization\CLDR\DataLayer\LocaleCache")
```

Already tried to restart installation, deleting the whole folder and then re-extract the archive

---

Screenshot:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fd51I.png)

Comment: Can you show us screen shots of the installation?

Comment: @FranCerezo Added.

Comment: Please share more details, and your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think error happens at copy files start, it may be a permission files problem.
Try to set read and write permissions to everybody on PS installation directory.

EDIT:
In Windows 7 click right button mouse on folder and select Properties. Click on Security tab and here you can set users' permissions.

About install in a Flash Drive, FAT32 does not support permission management. Format it with NTFS or install on hard disk.

Comment: How? As far as I know such thing can only be done on Linux

Comment: I have xampp on Windows

Comment: See this for solution if you've mounted your drive in WSL Linux => https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/issues/16680

Comment: @user3256843 I have Windows 7 as I mentioned, so there isn't any WSL

Comment: @FranCerezo I have Xampp installed in a Flash Drive and there isn't any Security tab there BTW I tried to uncheck the Read-only checkbox that has a square on it with no results also tried to install a different language gives me the same error but with the different language code

Comment: Maybe trying with the default store checkbox unchecked can solve this but I need them :( BTW I think unchecking that wouldn't make sense because it's a permission problem

Comment: Found the command icacls it says: FOLDER No permissions are set. All users have full control

Comment: What is the Flash Drive format file? FAT, NTFS, ext3, ... ? I guess if you install on hard drive you will get any problem.

Comment: @FranCerezo Fat32

Comment: FAT32 does not support permission management. Fotmat it with NTFS or install on hard disk.

Comment: Installed on hard drive and the problem solved can u add it to solution?

Comment: Answer updated. I am glad that you fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks but just for correcting mistakes you wrote "Format" as "Fotmat" Sorry if I wrote it offensively but that's just for making the answer better and more understandable